# Need Help! Number Wizard in java?

Tags: java, processing

I was just trying to get `NumberWizard` to work on java and I couldn't quite get it. Or can you just not do it in java? I'm pretty stuck because I can only get it to guess one time.

I'm using Processing 3 and my code looks like this:

```
int max = 1000, min = 1, guess = 500;

void setup() {
  size(400, 400); 
  background(0); 
  println("welcome to NumberGuesser ");
  println("In this game you're gonna think of a "); 
  println("number and im gonna guess it as fast as possible ");
  println(" \n ");
  println("Now pick of a number between " + min + "and" + max);
  println("Great! now that you have picked a number ");
  println("Press the up-arrow if its more");
  println("and the down-arrow if it's less ");

  println("is it less or more than "+ guess + "? \nif more press up-arrow, if less press down-arrow");
}


void draw() { 
  if (key == CODED) {
    if (keyCode == 38) { // up-arrow
      min = guess;      
      nextGuess();
    } else if (keyCode == 40) { //down-arrow
      max = guess;
      nextGuess();
    } else if (keyCode == 13) { //return
      win();
    }
  }
}

void nextGuess() {
  frameRate(1);
  guess = (max + min) /2;
  println("Is it less or more than "+ guess + "? \nif more press up-arrow, if less press down-arrow ");
}

void win() {
  println("that was'nt hard at all, ezz pezz! ");
  noLoop();
}
```

Comment: This is not a [minimal, complete and verifyable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The `key` and `keycode` variables appear from out of nowhere.

Comment: @SeverityOne Please note the [tag:processing] tag. This is in fact a [mcve]. See also: [Processing != Java](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/321127/873165). This question is probably still too broad, but it is indeed a MCVE.

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note that the `draw()` function fires 60 times per second. Even after you call `frameRate(1)`, the `draw()` function fires once per second. Further note that all of your logic is inside your `draw()` function. So the guessing will happen on an interval.

You're also not checking whether the key is currently pressed. Note that the `key` and `keyCode` variables contain the most recently pressed key. You still need to check whether the key is currently pressed. You can use the `keyPressed` variable or the `keyPressed()` function for this.

If I were you, I'd modify my program to use the `keyPressed()` function to detect user input instead of polling for it in the `draw()` function.

Also, you need to get in the habit of [debugging your code](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/debugging). Try to isolate the problem to a specific line of code that's behaving differently from what you expected, instead of posting your full program and saying it's not working.

Comment: Okay, ill try that then, sorry for the things i did wrong in here, im new to this :)